# Call function from dll inside .exe every x seconds

Tags: c++, dll

I have coded a .dll in C++ that does some checks (if window is opened, kill a process if running etc).It export's one function. This function is imported to an .exe . When i start the exe everything goes fine!
But i would like to ask, Is there a way to loop dll's function every x seconds so it can perform checks all the time?

Thank you in advance!

```
void killMe(const char *filename)
{
HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
while (hRes)
{
    if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
            (DWORD)pEntry.th32ProcessID);
        if (hProcess != NULL)
        {
            TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }
    hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
}
CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}



extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void Chek(void) {

for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
    HWND Find = FindWindow(0, "NotePad");
    if (Find != 0){
        killMe("notepad.exe");
        Chek();
    }
}

}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
DWORD _reason,
LPVOID lpReserved
){

switch (_reason)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

    Chek();



case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:

case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

    break;
}

return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: If you're using a framework which supports timers, use them (or start using such a framework for this purpose). Or spawn a thread, have it run a loop of `sleep(x); callDll();`

Comment: What havevyou attempted to do? Show us your code

Comment: I made only the .dll  . I dont have the source of .exe I tried to call the function inside itself and it worked as i wanted to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use timer or do it in a thread. For example you can create a thread on DllLoad and the dll can be something like this:

```
while( continueKilling )
{
    killMe( "test" );
    Sleep( 5000 ); // 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Is there a good example to read so i can work on that? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13557/Creating-Threads-using-the-CreateThread-API

Comment: Thank you! I made a thread and a timer! Now is working more than fine!